# Variables with On/End Statements in AppleScript

Tags: variables, applescript, osx-mavericks

I'm experimenting with **on** and **end** statements in AppleScript.

Consider the following script.

```
set mytext to "Hello, World"  

on greeting(mytext)  
display dialog mytext default answer ""  
set othertext to text returned of result  
end greeting

greeting(mytext)  
say othertext
```

I want to carry over the variable *mytext* into **greeting** and I know I can do that by placing *mytext* in between parentheses after **greeting**. However, I want to carry over a variable set in the **greeting** statement, *othertext*, to the rest of the code.

In the end, I want the script to set *othertext* to whatever is entered in the text box, and after **greeting** the script says *othertext*. I tried putting *othertext* in between parentheses after *end greeting* but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return as many variables as you wish from a handler by returning either a list (in the example below) or a record.  As long as you know how to find what you want, it works splendidly.

```
set mytext to "Hello, World"

on greeting(mytext)
    display dialog mytext default answer ""
    return {(text returned of result), "Another Variable"}
end greeting

set othertext to greeting(mytext)
say othertext's item 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set mytext to "Hello, World"  

on greeting(mytext)  
    display dialog mytext default answer ""  
    return text returned of result  
end greeting

set othertext to greeting(mytext)  
say othertext
```

Edited to add:

```
set mytext to "Hello, World"  

on greeting(mytext)  
    display dialog mytext default answer "" buttons {"Yes", "No", "Maybe"} 
    return {text returned of result, button returned of result}
end greeting

set {othertext, chosenaction} to greeting(mytext)
```

Comment: Great, how do you do that with two variables instead of one though?